# Given 3 tables I have to find this particular query, how do I do that?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a homework problem.

Given the tables in a database:

`M_Cast(ID,MID,PID)` where ID is primary key.

`Person(PID,Name,DOB,Gender)` where PID is primary key.

`Movie(MID,title,year)` where MID is primary,

and I have to answer query like: Find the actors who have acted in more movies in 2005 than any other year.

using mysql.

I am trying to do this:

```
select distinct(PID),Name
from M_Cast natural join Person natural join Movie
where (*query1*) 
> (*query2*);
```

So now query1 is number of movies each actor has done in 2005, and query2 is maximum number of movies each actor has done in any year other than 2005. So I want to know how do I answer query2?

Comment: Please do not keep adding "edit"s, edit your post so that it clearly states & presents your question as of the time you edit.

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: Distinct is not a function. And it says, distinct *rows*. So the parentheses around PID have nothing to do with the distinct. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: @philipxy I think i get your point, there could be multiple years with same max number of movies and my code is wrong I need to change it.

Comment: You still ask 3 times. Ask once clearly. You don't need the last 2 paragraphs, cut them. Eg the 2nd last just repeats the code --except it uses "point to" instead of "is", and "each" actor should be "that" actor, and "compare" is a vague description of "greater than". Repeating yourself only makes things unclear. Unless they are already unclear, when trying a bunch of different ways might help people to figure out what one is  trying but failing to say. It's actually poor writing that lets one tell oneself that one has tried many times when really one hasn't really tried once.

Comment: Now that we know what query you are trying to write: What have you tried? What parts can you do? Eg Rows where their number of movies is 2. Where it is coumn N. Where their number of movies in 2005 is 2. Where it is is column M. What is query1? What are their movie years? What are their movie years & movies? What are their movie years & number of movies? What are their non-2005 movie years & number of movies? Etc.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    select m.year, count(*) num_of_movies, p.PID from Movie m inner join 
    M_Cast mc on m.MID = mc.MID inner join Person p on p.PID = mc.PID
    group by m.year order by num_of_movies DESC, m.year DESC
```

If you want only for 2005, then you can add the where condition m.year = '2005'

Do like this for the query2:

```
    ;with query2 as (select m.year, count(*) num_of_movies, p.PID from Movie 
    m inner join 
    M_Cast mc on m.MID = mc.MID inner join Person p on p.PID = mc.PID
    where m.years <> '2005'
    group by m.year order by num_of_movies DESC, m.year DESC) 

    select distinct(PID),Name from M_Cast natural join Person natural join 
    Movie where (*query1*) = (select Max(num_of_movies) from query2)
```

take a look, it may help

Comment: Is it syntactically correct? Does it actually start with a semicolon?

Comment: yes, this is sql syntax, are u wokring with? mysql?

Comment: @ash, this is a cte (common table expression)

Comment: as i know, mysql will support `cte` syntax from version 8.0

Comment: You cannot select p.PID, you didn't group by it. Since you are combining that with a subquery order by, you seem to wrongly think that a non-standard MySQL misuse of group by always returns the "first" value of a non-grouped column per group, but order by without limit/top does nothing in a subquery *and* the select picks an *unspecified* value from the PIDs.

Comment: how do I run this query? The query2? it's giving me an error when I run it without the very first semi colon, `you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'query2 as (select m.year, count(*) num_of_movies, p.PID from Movie 
    m inner ' at line 1`

Comment: which mysql version are you using? it should look like this is mysql 8.0:     
  WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT n + 1, q * 2, p * 2 FROM cte WHERE n < 5
)
SELECT * FROM cte;

Comment: @alaa_sayegh I am using mysql version 14.14 in ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @ash The CTE general form is a comma-separated list of name & optional column list AS subquery followed by a SELECT using the names. The semicolon is not part of it, it is a coding style for commands, and you don't want it in a subquery. But see my comments re problems with this answer. PS 14.14 is the version of the command line client part of the MySQL distribution. 
"MySQL version" means the MySQL distribution version, given by `SELECT VERSION();`. Eg 5.7.

Comment: The question's overall query with equality of query1 & 2 doesn't work, see my comment on the question. An actor's 2005 must be *greater than* (the max of) all other years for them.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
SELECT Person.* from Person
inner join (
    select PID from (
        select M_Cast.PID as PID, Movie.year as year, count(*) as cnt from Movie
        inner join M_Cast
        on Movie.MID = M_Cast.MID
        group by M_Cast.PID, Movie.year
    ) t
    group by PID
    having max(case when year = 2005 then cnt else 0 end) > max(case when year <> 2005 then cnt else 0 end)
) tt
on Person.PID = tt.PID
```

Comment: I think it works fine but still doesn't answer my queries.

Comment: @ash What does works "fine" mean? What does "doesn't answer my queries" mean?

Comment: @philipxy actually my question is how do I answer query2 (refer question), your solution perfectly answers the assignment problem but that wasn't my question.